# Python Pandas - non-continuous time series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series

Is there a way within Pandas to create a time series that consists of selected clock times for each day of a period? For example: Let's take all days of 2018 as our dates, and for times (clock) 4 different times, like `[09:00, 10:35, 14:00, 15:50]`.

So what I want is a time series like:

```
2018-01-01 09:00
2018-01-01 10:35
2018-01-01 14:00
2018-01-01 15:50
2018-01-02 09:00
2018-01-02 10:35
2018-01-02 14:00
2018-01-02 15:50
2018-01-03 09:00
...
```

TIA,
T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a combination of pandas [date_range()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) and pandas [where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# Define times
times = ['00:00','09:00', '10:35', '14:00', '15:50']

# Define dates
start_date = '01.01.2018'
end_date = '31.12.2018'

# Create a list in minute resolution between start and end date
diff = pd.date_range(start_date,end_date,freq='T')

# Keep only the elements which match with the defined times in the list
filtered_hours = diff.where([mins in times for mins in diff.strftime('%H:%M')]).dropna()

print(filtered_hours)


DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 09:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 10:35:00', '2018-01-01 14:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 15:50:00', '2018-01-02 00:00:00',
               '2018-01-02 09:00:00', '2018-01-02 10:35:00',
               '2018-01-02 14:00:00', '2018-01-02 15:50:00',
               ...
               '2018-12-29 09:00:00', '2018-12-29 10:35:00',
               '2018-12-29 14:00:00', '2018-12-29 15:50:00',
               '2018-12-30 00:00:00', '2018-12-30 09:00:00',
               '2018-12-30 10:35:00', '2018-12-30 14:00:00',
               '2018-12-30 15:50:00', '2018-12-31 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=1821, freq='T')
```

**Put it into a Series with**

```
# Put it into a Series

val = np.arange(0,len(filtered_hours))

Ser = pd.Series(val,index=filtered_hours)

print(Ser)



2018-01-01 00:00:00       0
2018-01-01 09:00:00       1
2018-01-01 10:35:00       2
2018-01-01 14:00:00       3
2018-01-01 15:50:00       4
2018-01-02 00:00:00       5
2018-01-02 09:00:00       6
2018-01-02 10:35:00       7
2018-01-02 14:00:00       8
2018-01-02 15:50:00       9
2018-01-03 00:00:00      10
2018-01-03 09:00:00      11
2018-01-03 10:35:00      12
2018-01-03 14:00:00      13
2018-01-03 15:50:00      14
2018-01-04 00:00:00      15
2018-01-04 09:00:00      16
2018-01-04 10:35:00      17
```

Answer (score 3):

**You can do something like this which would be much faster than having loops:**

1.) Create a list of dates:

```
In [34]: start_dt = '2018-01-01'
# For whole year, use periods=365
In [45]: days_list = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(start_dt), periods=3) 
In [59]: days_list = [i.date() for i in days_list] # Keeping only date part
```

2.) Create a list of times:

```
In [38]: timelist = ['09:00', '10:35', '14:00', '15:50']
```

3.) Extend the list by repeating every element in the `days_list` 4 times, one for each time:

```
In [60]: import numpy as np
In [61]: days_list = np.repeat(days_list, 4)
```

4.) Extend the timelist by multiplying it by unique dates in days_list to have the same length has days_list:

So, since we used `periods=3` while creating days_list. So, extending timelist by the same factor;

```
In [64]: timelist = timelist * 3
```

5.) Creating dataframe:

```
In [65]: df = pd.DataFrame()
In [66]: df['Date'] = days_list
In [68]: df['time'] = timelist
```

Final output:

```
In [78]: df
Out[78]: 
          Date   time
0   2018-01-01  09:00
1   2018-01-01  10:35
2   2018-01-01  14:00
3   2018-01-01  15:50
4   2018-01-02  09:00
5   2018-01-02  10:35
6   2018-01-02  14:00
7   2018-01-02  15:50
8   2018-01-03  09:00
9   2018-01-03  10:35
10  2018-01-03  14:00
11  2018-01-03  15:50
```

Answer (score 1):

```
timelist = ['09:00', '10:35', '14:00', '15:50']
dayslist = []
for day in range(1, 366):
    for time in timelist:
        dayslist.append(str(day) + ' ' + time)

print(dayslist)
```

You should be able to import time and loop through it to replace the days with whichever dateformat you desire
Then, you can input your list into the Pandas DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({‘DateTime’: dayslist})
print(df)
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way I've currently solved it, but I was thinking that there might be a way within Pandas time series functionality to do the same without explicit loops.